# Is the DRBD configuration-file format a standard one?

Tags: python, linux, parsing, configuration-files, drbd

Is the [configuration-file format](https://docs.linbit.com/man/v9/drbd-conf-5/) that DRBD uses a somewhat standard one with existing parsers in Python or is it not which would require me to write my own parser?

Example:

```
resource server42 {
        volume 0 {
                device          /dev/drbd9;
                disk            /dev/vg01/server42-root-drbd;
                meta-disk       /dev/vg01/server42-root-metadata;
        }
        volume 1 {
                device          /dev/drbd10;
                disk            /dev/vg01/server42-swap-drbd;
                meta-disk       /dev/vg01/server42-swap-metadata;
        }
        volume 2 {
                device          /dev/drbd11;
                disk            /dev/vg01/server42-temp-drbd;
                meta-disk       /dev/vg01/server42-temp-metadata;
        }
        volume 3 {
                device          /dev/drbd12;
                disk            /dev/vg01/server42-var-drbd;
                meta-disk       /dev/vg01/server42-var-metadata;
        }
        on server23 {
                address         10.20.30.40:7796;
        }
        on server24 {
                address         10.20.30.41:7796;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's proprietary. The DRBD utils ship `drbdadm` which has a `dump-xml` option, you could use that to translate the configurations from their proprietary format into xml. Hope that helps!